# finding a basis for $W^\perp$ and understanding it.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given

$$
w_1 =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix},w_2=  \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
let $W$ be the subspace spanned by the given vectors. Find a basis for $W^\perp$ Now my problem is, how do envision this? They do the following:

They use the vectors as rows. Then they say that W is the row space of A, and so it holds that $W^\perp = null(A)$ . and we thus solve for $Ax=0$

Now my problem is: how do i envision this? Why is $W^\perp = null(A)$ I dont like learning these kinds fo things, is there a way to understand this? WHY is this the case, why do they specifically let A use $w_1$ and $w_2$ as the rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a vector ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. You want to find the solutions to the system $$\begin{cases}{\bf x}\cdot {\bf w}_1=0\\{\bf x}\cdot {\bf w}_2=0\end{cases}$$ See? Then find a basis for this.

Comment: why not two variables? why are we not taking them as columns? Thats moreover my question, though I get your intuition

Comment: What do you mean by "two variables"? We want $x$ to be simultaneously orthogonal to $w_1$ and $w_2$, so it will be orthogonal to all the elements of their span.

Comment: I mean, why are they using $w_1$ and $w_2$ as rows? Why not as columns? Thats my main pickle with this.

Comment: ohhhh, of course. how could it not be $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_3$, else we couldnt even do the dot product.

d'oh

Comment: @WiseStrawberry You *can* do it with columns, as long as you start using row vectors as inputs, so that the matrix dimensions are compatible.

Comment: dimensions help for checking if what I'm doing is correct. A lot of the times. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate somewhat on Peter's post, we note that for any two column vectors of real entries:
$$
v\cdot  w=v^Tw
$$
So our system is simply
$$
\begin{cases}
{w_1}^Tx = 0\\
{w_2}^Tx = 0
\end{cases}
$$

That is,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
{w_1}^Tx \\
{w_2}^Tx 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
And in case you need me to tell you where this is going, that is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
– & {w_1}^T & –\\
- & {w_2}^T & –
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
| \\
x \\
|
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: damn. that does explain a lot.

Comment: Dear @omno... Oop, you beat me to it, but since I spent so much time typing I hope you don't mind if I just vote for yours and leave my answer up.

Comment: @rschwieb the more the merrier, and the quickest answer is not generally the best.  The upvote is appreciated also :)

Comment: whats up with the last matrix? what are the '-' on the left and right of $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: emphasizing that it's a row vector in each row.  Thought it looks better

Comment: Now I'm a little bit more consistent about it.  Maybe I should have just kept it simple though...

Answer (score 2):

*Why is $W^\perp =null(A)$?*

Well, $W^\perp=\{x\in V\mid w_1\cdot x=w_2\cdot x=0\}$

and

$null(A)=\left\{x\in V \mid Ax^\top=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} \right\}$

The connection is that $Ax^\top$ computes exactly $w_1\cdot x$ and $w_2\cdot x$.