# Question about Orthogonal Complements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

I had difficulties understanding this question. Could you give me some advice how to approach this question? I couldn't create the relationship between the given features.

> Let $x =\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$ and $W=\operatorname{span}\left\{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}}_{v_1},\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}}_{v_2}\right\}\leqslant\Bbb R^4$. Find vectors $w_1\in W$ and $w_2\in W^\perp$ with $x = w_1 + w_2.$

What can I use to solve this question?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization?

Comment: Like $w_1=c_1v_1+c_2v_2$ then solve $v_i.(x-w_1)=0$ for $c_1,c_2$. Should I expand it to a full answer?

Comment: Yes I'm @caffeinemachine.

Comment: It would be great. I couldn't figure it out @AlexeyBurdin

Comment: @Cheesecake I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand where to start with. This topic is new for me and this question was very different than the ones I've solved. This isn't my homework, this is for practice to my final exam. And about the formatting, I know it is terrible, but I'm new to this website and I'm just starting to get used to it. I searched for the formatting settings on the site and on internet but I can only find how to make bold or italic. Yes, I am aware that you've edited but like I said I don't know how to do it. Could you please give me a link so I can learn it? I'm sorry.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Comment: Find a basis for [$\mathbf{W}^{\perp}$ given spanning vectors of $\mathbf{W}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21757/721644)  and 
 [Find the basis for the orthogonal complement $U^{\perp}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3595451/721644) and [finding a basis for $W^\perp$ and understanding it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/439945/721644)

Comment: Also, an abstract duplicate of [Find a basis for $W^\perp$ for $W=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x_1-x_2-x_3=0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763728/721644).

Comment: @Kaan, if you find some answer useful, make sure you accept it.

Comment: @Cheesecake Thank you I will study on the editing. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Now I can understand, I have also looked at my notes again. Thank you. The exam will mainly cover eigenvalues/vectors, so I focused on them and could unfortunately not focus on orthogonality. I know about the policies of this site and therefore I always show effort on my questions, this time I could really not understand. You can check at my other questions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Orchid_2.718281828 Oh, I've been just learning the system I forgot, thank you I will

Comment: @Kaan, no problem, just search the site.  Glad to help. Remember, always clarify everything in the post. I understand it now when you said it, but next time, please write down what you haven't covered. 

Comment: @Cheesecake I will, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write down the following system:
$AX=0$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\-1&-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=0$$
The solution space to this system is $\Omega\leqslant\Bbb R^4$ and $\Omega=W^\perp$. Solve the system, find a basis and express $x$ in terms of it.
Obviously $x_4=0$.
$x_1+x_2=-x_3$
$x_1=t, x_2=s$

Your solution is of the following form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}t\\s\\-t-s\\0\end{bmatrix}=t\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\implies\Omega=W^\perp=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Now we have: $$W\oplus\Omega=\Bbb R^4\iff\Bbb R^4=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

I hope it is now straight-forward.

This is the most efficient method. Just bear in mind the solution space $\Omega=W^\tau$, where $W$ is the **row-space**.

> This is a concrete-explanation of [@PedroTamaroff's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/439946/721644).

Answer (score 1):

As **caffeinemachine** didn't implement the answer yet, I'd stole the idea and implement both approaches.
The first is more simple.
Let's $v_1'=\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}$ and $v_2'=v_2+av_1'$ for such $a$, that $v_1'.v_2'=0$:
$$v_1'.v_2'=0$$
$$v_1'.(v_2+av_1')=0$$
$$v_1'.v_2+a=0$$
$$v_1'.v_2=-a,$$
so $v_2'=v_2-(v_1'.v_2)v_1'$ and $v_2''=\frac{v_2'}{|v_2'|}$.
Further, include $x$ into the set: $$\begin{cases}
x'=x-bv_1'-cv_2''\\
x'.v_1'=0\\
x'.v_2''=0
\end{cases}$$
so $x'$ will be $w_2$ and $bv_1'+cv_2''$ will be $w_1$.
$$\begin{cases}
x'=x-bv_1'-cv_2''\\
(x-bv_1'-cv_2'').v_1'=0\\
(x-bv_1'-cv_2'').v_2''=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x'=x-bv_1'-cv_2''\\
x.v_1'-bv_1'.v_1'-cv_2''.v_1'=0\\
x.v_2''-bv_1'.v_2''-cv_2''.v_2''=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x'=x-bv_1'-cv_2''\\
x.v_1'-b\cdot 1-c\cdot 0=0\\
x.v_2''-b\cdot 0-c\cdot 1=0
\end{cases}$$
so $x'=x-(x.v_1')v_1'-(x.v_2'')v_2''$ and we're done.

The second, straightforward approach:
Let's say $x=w_1+w_2,\, w_1=av_1+bv_2,\, v_1.w_2=0,\, v_2.w_2=0$ so we have the system of linear equations and [solve them for $a$, $b$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%7D.%28%7B1%2C+2%2C+0%2C+-2%7D-x*%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%7D-y*%7B-1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%29%3D0%2C+%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%7D.%28%7B1%2C+2%2C+0%2C+-2%7D-x*%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%7D-y*%7B-1%2C+-1%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%29%3D0): $a=-\frac12$, $b=-\frac32$, so $w_1=-\frac12 v_1-\frac32 v_2$, $w_2=x-w_1$.

Comment: It's not needed to find a $W^\perp$ basis here therefore it's much more simple than to guess $2$ more linearly independent vectors to extend $W$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$, IMHO.

Comment: We can also solve it via matrix. Since $W$ is a row-space of the coefficient matrix $A\in M_{2\times 4},\Omega=W^\perp$